# Error when trying to update npm on live server?

Tags: command-line, npm

I run this command and after a while it shows: Killed. Why?

```
sudo npm install -g npm
extract → gunzTarPerm     ▌ ╢█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
Killed
```

I'm stuck with version 3.5.2 when I have 3.10.10 on my dev machine. I'm not able to upgrade.

Still 3.5.2.

npm -v  still says 3.5.2.

Tried with this: sudo npm install -g npm@3.10.10

Now, I've partly got something right. The version is now 3.10.10. But now I get some other error.

```
Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 7.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add a swap file to my server because it ran out of memory.

Comment: You ran out of memory while trying to install npm? How much RAM does your server have?

Comment: The smallest droplet at Digital Ocean - 512 MB. I created a 1 GB swap file.

Comment: That would have been useful information to include in your question. The word "server" tends to mean lots of RAM, not a VPS that with 512 MB of RAM.